# Parsing CSV file where for particular field, I have multiple csv records

Tags: c#

All the parsed fields are added to a list. Hence, it will also add the field with multiple values separated with commas as an individual item of original list. But the first and last item that I am reading contains char '\' for that field which holds multiple values.

e.g

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,"d,e,f"
aaa,bbb,ccc,"d,,f"
```

Since, csv is comma delimiter. I have used split on char ','.
For the first line, output looks like this.

```
csvFieds[0] = "aaa"
csvFields[1] = "bbb"
csvFields[2] = "ccc"
csvFields[3] = "\"d"
csvFields[4] = "e"
csvFields[5] = "\"f"
```

I have tried using split on index 3 and 4, but it doesn't work.

Do you  have experience working with csv inside csv ?

Comment: You will need to provide more information.  This is too vague.  The example shown isn't clear enough of what you are trying to do and what isn't working.

Comment: Couldn't you use another separator (one which wouldn't be in any of your "field", like `~`) ?

Comment: My format in above example is messed up. 
This is what the first line is  aaa,bbb,ccc,"d,e,f". When reading a csv file. 
 

And the output is given above.

Comment: Raphael, csv is comman delimeter. There's no point of using another separator.

Comment: @mbeckish, since only the last field contains multiple values separated with commas. So, I loop through from the index it starts to have multiple values until last index. I do not think, having comma delimiter on my field which contains multiple values, won't impact. Problem, here the first and last item from that field contains '\'. Tried using splitting on character '\' but doesn't work.

Comment: You appear to be on [step 2](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble)

Answer (score 0):

I simply use Trim() function.

```
csvFields[3].Trim('\"');
```

Trick is I have to include the double quotes too.